# i changed dns server name if i dont use https the homepage is redirected to old dns

Tags: php, amazon-ec2, dns, apache2, bitnami

I am a new to PHP and Apache server and i was asked to do few changes to DNS in the AWS Ec2 instance of a PHP application where i changed the `config['base_url']= puredata.digitowork.com`, after i made these changes when i use the url without **https** protocol, its redirecting to the old DNS, what are the changes i need to do to avoid this issue.

[image: I am attaching a picture about what is happening when i enter the domain name in browser.]

I am not able to understand why its redirecting.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you have a redirection in place previously? I believe that this redirection is cached in the web browser and that's why you are getting redirected. Can you use an incognito window or a different browser to check if the problem persists?

Comment: No i too thought the same initially but I kept the question after I tried on different browsers.

Comment: It seems you have a redirection in Apache that is forcing https and your domain when accessing the server. I don't know if you recently modified the Apache's configuration but you can check if you have any RewriteRule in your server by running this command `sudo egrep -Ri RewriteRule /opt/bitnami/`. Thanks

Comment: yes there is a link in previous dns name in bitnami.conf, can i change it to my present link

Comment: Thank you @JotaMartos it worked changing rewriterule.

Comment: Perfect! I'll move that information to an answer of the thread.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you have a redirection in Apache that is forcing https and your domain when accessing the server. I don't know if you recently modified the Apache's configuration but you can check if you have any `RewriteRule` in your server by running this command

```
sudo egrep -Ri RewriteRule /opt/bitnami/
```